# jQuery Confirm Dialog continues to submit form when okay is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I use jQuery [confirm plugin](https://github.com/myclabs/jquery.confirm).

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".confirm").confirm({
        text: "Are you sure?",
        title: "Confirmation required",
        confirm: function() {
            //when I click confirm it will redirect to the link
        },
        cancel: function() {
            //do something
        },
        confirmButton: "Yes",
        cancelButton: "No"
    });
});
```

Here is the `form`:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <button type="submit" class="confirm">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So when I click the "Yes" button it continues to submit the form.

By the way, when I click the `submit` button the confirm dialog is showing up quite well but nothing is happened when I click the "yes" or "no" button.

Comment: Probably `return true` and `return false` in the confirm and cancel functions.

Comment: i just added on the confirm button $("form").submit() and it went fine but when I try using a normal href it won't redirect to the url because its not a form. something like this

<a href="somewhere.php>LINK</a>

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the option `post` on true.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".confirm").confirm({
        text: "Are you sure?",
        title: "Confirmation required",
        confirm: function() {
            //when I click confirm it will redirect to the link
        },
        cancel: function() {
            //do something
        },
        confirmButton: "Yes",
        cancelButton: "No",
        post: true
    });
});
```

Read about the `post` option [here](https://github.com/myclabs/jquery.confirm#options)

Comment: Added a link to the Options in the documentation for further reference.

Comment: Sorry, i will do that the next time! Ty

Comment: i just added on the confirm button $("form").submit() and it went fine but when I try using a normal href it won't redirect to the url because its not a form. something like this

<a href="somewhere.php>LINK</a>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the buttons in JavaScript dialog. For above javascript code, we should some plugin for custom confirm box.

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
<button type="submit" class="confirm">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".confirm").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $(".confirm").confirm({
    text: "Are you sure?",
    title: "Confirmation required",
    confirm: function() {
        $("form").submit();
    },
    cancel: function() {
        //do something
    },
    confirmButton: "Yes",
    cancelButton: "No"
});

       });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Question asked. The OP is using a "custom confirm box" already.

Comment: Add custom confirm box inside class.Check update data.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the button type button and manage the button click whith your confirm window:

```
<button type="button" id="trigger" class="confirm">Submit</button>
...
$("#trigger").submit(confirmWindow);
...
function confirmWindow(){
    // Put here your confirm window code ...
}
...
$("#yourform").submit(); // ... and send the form if the user choose "yes"
```

:)